# Customizing module per client

Tags: design, architecture

let's say I have 3 customers A, B and C.

I have application (whatever what this application is) I have front-end (let's say in angular2) and back-end (in Spring).

On the beggining I have one common version of front-end and back-end, but after some time customer A wants something unique on front (what have to be handle special in backend) and customer B wants it too, similarly with C. At this moment from one back-end and one front-end we have 3 front-ends and 3 back-end (one for each customer) I don't think so it is ok to have only one backend for every customers).

What is the best for customizing this application for every customer? (Let say next I will have customer D, E, F... Z).

If my question is unclear let me know. I am not native English speaker.

Comment: There is no "best" way. But I can tell you an often successful strategy: try to keep it one frontend and one backend, and manage the customization by configuration. And if you want a more specific answer, I recommend to ask a more specific question, ideally about your *real* situation, with some *real* context, not some imaginary situation about unknown applications and features.

Comment: But how is the proper way to customize it? What should I use to customize it? Let say there is a page who has button, and for every client this button will do different thing. How can i customize it?

Comment: @Highhopes What you're looking for is a "feature toggle" which I mentioned in my answer. There are many approaches you could implement. It could be as simple as an if-statement that checks a user preference or system property. However, it sounds like you have two separate use cases, and if so, you really need two separate buttons. If you just need to dynamically swap out some algorithm or task, there are patterns for that, like Strategy and Command. You can drive the runtime behavior with configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm noticing some fundamental issues with the basis of your question.

The first issue is architectural. Strictly speaking, requirements changing on the front end (GUI) should be orthogonal to the other components of your application. Consider a bulletin board application. If one customer wants a dashboard with widgets and another wants a streaming feed, this should be a change in the presentation layer, and should not require any changes to the business logic or lower components. If the customer's requirement entails changes that cross-cut the architecture, then what you're describing is a **use case**. Use cases cut vertically through your architecture because they typically require new code in multiple layers, sometimes from the presentation layer all the way down to the database. Measuring the blast radius of the customer's enhancement request is critical to effective planning.

The next issue is a product management issue. You should not be making a mess of your software trying to meet the myriad demands of every customer. You must have a process for **hearing** the demands of your customers, **evaluating** the cost of these demands versus their benefit, and only turning those demands into requirements when the benefits outweigh the risks and there is sufficient consensus among your customer base. Otherwise, the application becomes bloated with features that nobody uses, and technical debt piles up. *The software degrades for **all** of your customers*. This is true whether you have 3 customers or 3 million.

Now, let's say you've done cost/benefit analysis on some demand from your customer base, and decided to add it to the product roadmap. You need to measure the impact of that requirement in architectural terms. Is it limited to the presentation layer, such as the dashboards versus feeds example? Or is it a vertical **use case**, like an in-app messaging feature? In either case, you can provide the same application to all of your customers if you allow them to **configure** it. Let them decide between dashboards and feeds by providing a **[feature toggle](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html)**. Design the messaging feature as a **[plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing))**, and let them install it if they want it.

Your dilemma is solved by practical architectural design, and shrewd product management strategies. If you want your product to endure, I recommend studying software design at the enterprise level. The lessons you learn when you're trying to solve problems at that scale are universally valuable. Here's some good literature to start with:

[Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture - Martin Fowler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)

[Clean Architecture - Robert C. Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134494164)

[Working Effectively with Legacy Code - Michael Feathers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) *(Yes, your own code from last week can be "legacy" code!)*

Comment: Idea with plugins is fine, but what if one plugin depends on another one?

Comment: @High hopes Then you will need a mechanism for mapping out a dependency graph between plugins, and "activate" them in the correct order according to that graph. In other words, if plugin B requires plugin A, activating B will first activate A. However, if you're the author of these plugins, you're probably better off designing them so that they don't depend on each other.